# How to solve the performance/memory issues related with having entities that depend on other entities in DDD?

Tags: c#, java, oop, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

Assuming that I'm using no ORM, and following DDD, consider the following case:

A `Project` has a set of `File`s.

I've created both a `Project` and a `ProjectRepository` and a `File` and a `FileRepository` classes.

My original idea was having all the `File` entities for a given `Project` being passed to it in its constructor. This Project instance would, of course, be created through the `ProjectRepository`.

The problem is that if I have a million files (and although I won't have a million files, I'll have enough ones to make this take a while), I'll have to load them all, even when I don't really need them.

What's the standard approach to this? I can't think of anything better than to pass a `FileRepository` to each `Project` instance.

Comment: Is it a web application? In what context do you need to access the files? Do you need the same model for both commands and queries?

Answer (score 4):

Since you mention DDD: if there are two repositories it indicates that there are two **Aggregate Roots**. The whole point of the Aggregate Root concept is that each root is responsible for its *entire object graph*.

If you try to mix Files into a Project object graph, then the ownership of the Files is ambiguous. In other words, don't do this:

```
project
- file
- file
- file
```

Either treat them as two (associated) object graphs, or remodel the API so that there's only a single Aggregate Root (repository).

Comment: There is only one repository (a singleton).

Comment: In your question, you specifically describe two repositories (ProjectRepository and FileRepository)...

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard way. This is domain driven design, so it depends on the domain, if you ask me.
Maybe you could add some more domain to your design.
You only have two concepts: a Project and a File. But you say you don't want to load the file (assuming that File will always load the content of the file).

So maybe you should think about a FileReference, which is a lightweight representation of a file (Name, Path, Size?).
For me it sounds like your problem is the handling of a large set of files and not OOP.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a [service layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) which your clients interact with which co-ordinates the repositories and returns the domain entities. This would provide a better separation of concerns; I personally don't think that your client should have access to your repositories.